# how to get exact matched data between two tables -SQL or pandas

Tags: sql, pandas

I have two tables and would like to have the exact matched rows between two tables like in desired output data.

```
table 1:
    PID     PDate     Col1    Col2     Amount
    100     20210624  AAA     PPP      10000
    100     20210624  AAA     PPP       888
    100     20210624  AAA     CAT      10000
    100     20210624  AAA     CAT       888
    222     20210624  MMM     PPP       700 
    222     20210624  DDD     PPP       660 
    666     20210624  DDD     CAT       500 

table 2:
    PID     PDate     Col1    Col2     Amount
    100     20210624  AAA     PPP      10000
    100     20210624  AAA     PPP       888
    100     20210624  AAA     PPP      10000
    100     20210624  AAA     PPP       888
    222     20210624  MMM     PPP       700 
    222     20210624  DDD     PPP       660 
    666     20210624  DDD     CAT       500 
    666     20210624  DDD     CAT       500 

Desired output:
PID     PDate     Col1    Col2     Amount
100     20210624  AAA     PPP      10000
100     20210624  AAA     PPP       888
222     20210624  MMM     PPP       700 
222     20210624  DDD     PPP       660 
666     20210624  DDD     CAT       500
```

I tried with creating row_number() over (partition by PID,PDate,Col1,Col2 order by PID,PDate,Col1,Col2 Amount) and then joining them but the order varies for the PID 100.
If I dont add row number, then I get PID 666 twice in my output but only one row matches between two tables.
How do I get the right output in sql or pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your desired output you could [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) after [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
>>> table_one.merge(table_two)
   PID     PDate Col1 Col2  Amount
0  100  20210624  AAA  PPP   10000
1  100  20210624  AAA  PPP   10000
2  100  20210624  AAA  PPP     888
3  100  20210624  AAA  PPP     888
4  222  20210624  MMM  PPP     700
5  222  20210624  DDD  PPP     660
6  666  20210624  DDD  CAT     500
7  666  20210624  DDD  CAT     500

>>> table_one.merge(table_two).drop_duplicates()
   PID     PDate Col1 Col2  Amount
0  100  20210624  AAA  PPP   10000
2  100  20210624  AAA  PPP     888
4  222  20210624  MMM  PPP     700
5  222  20210624  DDD  PPP     660
6  666  20210624  DDD  CAT     500
```